# WCF XmlWriterTraceListener does not log message

Tags: wcf, iis, logging, soap

I've got an IIS application that host SOAP endpoints that I am trying to add logging to for debugging purposes. The calls are executed and processed, but the message contents are in question. I need to verify the contents before any processing is done.

I've located the web.config file and added logging as follows

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics performanceCounters="ServiceOnly">  
    <messageLogging   
         logEntireMessage="true"   
         logMalformedMessages="true"  
         logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"   
         logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"  
         maxMessagesToLog="300000"  
         maxSizeOfMessageToLog="65535000"/>  
  </diagnostics>  
</system.serviceModel>
```

And

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>        
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose">
      <listeners>
        <add name="MyCustomLogging"  
             type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"  
             initializeData="C:\Temp\MyCustomLogging.svclog" />  
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

The logging works fine when I test it with smaller messages (< 2 KB) - [screenshot from Service Trace Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1QfI.png)

But when the real integration is triggered, the messages sent across are much lager, around 250KB each. And those are not logged. I just get an empty MessageLogTraceRecord element in my trace - [screenshot from Service Trace Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z0MK.png)

The size might not be the real problem, but that is the only thing I can think of. The real messages are sent by a third party and I don't have access to their system, nor do I know what they are using to send the messages. But the messages are successfully received by our application and processed, so they do make it over.

Any pointers/thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.
I needed to add

```
<endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true" messageFlowTracing="true" />
```

in the diagnostics tag, underneath the messageLogging tag, like this

```
<diagnostics performanceCounters="ServiceOnly">  
    <messageLogging   
         logEntireMessage="true"   
         logMalformedMessages="true"  
         logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"   
         logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"  
         maxMessagesToLog="300000"  
         maxSizeOfMessageToLog="65535000"/>  
    <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true" messageFlowTracing="true" />
  </diagnostics>
```